# ie8 and ie9 loads <head> content in <body>

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I've got a funny issue with some older versions of internet explorer.

On the following website [www.inzone.dk](http://www.inzone.dk) the shop is working fine, and all html is rendered correctly. On the cart however I notice that the source code is displaying the `<head>` content correctly, but when I view the source code in the f12 developer tools, I'm met with only the title inside the `<head>` content, and all meta tags and css loaded in the `<body>`

This is not an issue in ie10 or ie11, nor is it in Firefox or Chrome, so I'm quite frankly baffled.

Can you help me out here?

EDIT: Added `<header>`  html

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Indkøbskurv Billige corsager hos Corsage-eksperten.dk</title>
    <base href="http://www.corsage-eksperten.dk/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link href="/index.php?route=feed/latest_products_rss&amp;currency=DKK" rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/theme/polianna/stylesheet/stylesheet.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/theme/polianna/stylesheet/responsive.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/theme/polianna/stylesheet/camera.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/theme/polianna/stylesheet/accordion.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/theme/polianna/stylesheet/cloud-zoom.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/theme/polianna/stylesheet/topmenu.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/theme/polianna/stylesheet/news.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/theme/polianna/stylesheet/fast_order.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/ui/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/colorbox/colorbox.css" media="screen">

    <script type="text/javascript" async="" src="http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        if (!window.jQuery) {
            document.write('<script src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"><\/script>');
        }
    </script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        if (!window.jQuery.ui) {
            document.write('<script src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/ui/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"><\/script>');
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/common.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
    <!-------------------------------Polianna js---------------------------------------------------------------->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/theme/polianna/js/custom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/theme/polianna/js/menu_script.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/theme/polianna/js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/theme/polianna/js/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/theme/polianna/js/jquery.gpCarousel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/theme/polianna/js/newselect.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/theme/polianna/js/jquery.slick.1.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/theme/polianna/js/cloud-zoom.1.0.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/theme/polianna/js/jquery.tinycarousel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/theme/polianna/js/jquery.accordion.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" src="catalog/view/theme/polianna/js/jquery.tipsy.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script language="javascript" src="fastorder/fast_order.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script language="javascript" src="catalog/view/theme/polianna/js/scroll/scrolltopcontrol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!--[if IE 7]> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/theme/default/stylesheet/ie7.css" />
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/theme/default/stylesheet/ie6.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/DD_belatedPNG_0.0.8a-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    DD_belatedPNG.fix('#logo img');
    </script>
    <![endif]-->
    <style type="text/css">
        body{ 
            background-color: #EEEEEE; 
            background-image: url("catalog/view/theme/polianna/image/pattern/overlay6.png"); 
        }
        #colorbox, #cboxOverlay, #cboxWrapper{ 
            z-index:10003; 
        }
        #header, .breadcrumb, #topfooter, .main{ 
            background-color: #000000; 
        }
        .colormenu{ 
            background-color: #FB2B75; 
        }
        .menuResp > li > a, .mobilemenu a, .navbar .textmenu{
            color: #FFFFFF; 
        }               
        .menuResp > li:hover > a{ 
            color: #FFFFFF; 
        }
        .menuResp > li:hover{ 
            background-color: #000000; 
        }
        .menuResp > li > div{ 
            background-color: #FFFFFF; 
        }
        .menuResp ul li a, .menuResp > li > div > ul > li > a, .menuResp > li > div > a { color: #000000; }             
        .menuResp ul li a:hover, .menuResp > li > div > a:hover, .menuResp > li > div > ul > li > a:hover{ 
            color: #FB2B75; 
        }               
        .menuResp > li > div > ul > li > a span{ 
            background-color: #F4F4F4; 
        }               
        .box-category > li > a, .box-account > li > a, .vtabs li a{ 
            color: #000000; 
        }               
        .box-category li a:hover, .box-category > li > a.active, .box-account li a:hover,
        .vtabs li a:hover, .vtabs li a.selected{ 
            color: #FB2B75; 
        }
        .box-category li  a:hover, .box-category > li > a.active, .vtabs li a.selected,
        .box-account li a:hover{ 
            border-color:#FB2B75; 
        }           
        #footer h3 { 
            color: #FFFFFF; 
        }               
        #footer .column a{ 
            color: #AAAAAA; 
        }               
        #footer .column a:hover{ 
            color: #FFFFFF; 
        }               
        #footer .column a:hover{ 
            background-color: #5E6067; 
        }               
        #footer, #powered, #powered a{ 
            color: #888888; 
        }               
        a, a b, .product-compare a{ 
            color: #FB2B75; 
        }               
        a:hover, .breadcrumb a:hover, .product-compare a:hover, .boxfeatured .name a:hover, .product-grid .name a:hover, .product-list .name a:hover, .boxfeatured .description a:hover,
        .product-list .description a:hover, .checkout-heading a:hover, .st-accordion ul li > a:hover, .top-nav #topbox > a:hover,
        .verticaltab .name a:hover, .product-grid .description a:hover, .box-news h4 a:hover, .htabs a.selected, .htabs a:hover{
            color: #FB2B75;
        }
        .block:hover{ 
            border-color: #FB2B75; 
        }
        .htabs a.selected, .htabs a:hover{ 
            border-top-color: #FB2B75; 
        }
        h1, h2, h4, .welcome #title, .product-info #opname, .verticaltab .name_categ a{ 
            color: #000000; 
        }               
        .boxfeatured .name a, .product-grid .name a, .product-list .name a, .verticaltab .name a{ 
            color: #000000; 
        }               
        #column-left .box .box-heading, #column-right .box .box-heading, .manufacturer-heading{ 
            color: #000000; 
        }               
        .box .box-heading, #fast_order_form .fast_order_center{ 
            color: #000000; 
        }               
        body, .boxfeatured .description a, .product-info .price-tax, .product-info .price .reward,
        .product-info .price .discount, .cart-total td b{ 
            color: #777777; 
        }               
        #cart > a{ 
            background-color: #FB2B75; 
        }               
        .boxfeatured .price, .product-grid .price,  .product-list .price, .product-info .price, .verticaltab .price, .compare-info .price{ color: #48D42D; }                
        .boxfeatured .price-old, .product-grid .price-old, .product-list .price-old, .product-info .price-old, .verticaltab .price-old, .compare-info .price-old{ 
            color: #888888; 
        }               
        .boxfeatured .price-new, .product-grid .price-new, .product-list .price-new, .product-info .price-new, .verticaltab .price-new, .compare-info .price-new{ 
            color: #FB2B75; 
        }               
        .savemoney{ 
            background-color: #FB2B75;
        }               
        .boxfeatured .cart a.button, .product-grid .cart a.button, .product-list .cart a.button, .cart input.button,
        .verticaltab .cart a.button, a.button, input.button, a.checkbut, a.redbutton, button, .box-news .readmore{ 
            background-color: #32353A; 
        }               
        .boxfeatured .cart a.button:hover, .product-grid .cart a.button:hover, .product-list .cart a.button:hover, .verticaltab .cart a.button:hover, .colorbox div#plus,
        .wishlist a:hover, .compare a:hover, .cart input.button:hover, a.button:hover, input.button:hover, a.checkbut:hover, button:hover,  a.redbutton:hover, .box-news .readmore:hover,
        a#arrow_left:hover, a#arrow_right:hover{ 
            background-color: #FB2B75; 
        }               
        .cart input.button, .product-list .cart a.button, .wishlist a:hover,  .compare a:hover, .product-info .compare a:hover, .product-info .wishlist a:hover,
        a.button, input.button, a.checkbut, a.redbutton, button, .box-news .readmore{ 
            color: #FFFFFF; 
        }               
        h1, .product-info .price,  .welcome #title, .verticaltab .name_categ a{ 
            font-size: nonepx; 
        }               
        h2{ 
            font-size: nonepx; 
        }               
        h3, #footer h3, .product-info #opname{ 
            font-size: nonepx; 
        }               
        h4, .box-news h4 a{ 
            font-size: nonepx; 
        }               
        .box .box-heading, #fast_order_form .fast_order_center{ 
            font-size: nonepx;
        }               
        #column-left .box .box-heading, #column-right .box .box-heading{ 
            font-size: nonepx; 
        }               
        .boxfeatured .name a, .product-grid .name a, .product-list .name a, .verticaltab .name a{ 
            font-size: nonepx; 
        }               
        body, input, textarea, select, .product-info .price-tax, .product-info .price .reward, .product-info .price .discount, .menuResp ul li a{ 
            font-size: nonepx; 
        }               
        .boxfeatured .price, .product-grid .price, .product-list .price, .verticaltab .price{ 
            font-size: nonepx; 
        }               
        .menuResp > li > a, .mobilemenu a, .navbar .textmenu{ 
            font-size: nonepx; 
        }               
        .menuResp > li > div > ul > li > a, .mobilemenu ul a{ 
            font-size: nonepx; 
        }               
        .box-category > li > a, .box-account > li > a, .vtabs li a { 
            font-size: nonepx; 
        }               
        .colormenu{ 
            width:1170px; 
        }
        .category-list{ 
            display:none;
        }           
        .product-grid .description{ 
            display:block; 
        }           
        @media only screen and (max-width: 1200px){
            .colormenu{ 
                min-width:270px; width: auto;
                }
        }   
    </style>     
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var _gaq = _gaq || [];
      _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-38099464-1']);
      _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

      (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
      })();
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("textarea").keypress(function(event) {
                if (event.keyCode != 13) return;
                e.preventDefault();
            var msg = $("textarea").val().replace("\n", "");
            if (!util.isBlank(msg)) {
                send(msg);
                $("textarea").val("");
            }
            return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="catalog/view/javascript/jquery.cluetip.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery.cluetip.js" type="text/javascript"></script>        
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a.title').cluetip({splitTitle: '|'});
            $('ol.rounded a:eq(0)').cluetip({splitTitle: '|', dropShadow: false, cluetipClass: 'rounded', showtitle: false});
            $('ol.rounded a:eq(1)').cluetip({cluetipClass: 'rounded', dropShadow: false, showtitle: false, positionBy: 'mouse'});
            $('ol.rounded a:eq(2)').cluetip({cluetipClass: 'rounded', dropShadow: false, showtitle: false, positionBy: 'bottomTop', topOffset: 70});
            $('ol.rounded a:eq(3)').cluetip({cluetipClass: 'rounded', dropShadow: false, sticky: true, ajaxCache: false, arrows: true});
            $('ol.rounded a:eq(4)').cluetip({cluetipClass: 'rounded', dropShadow: false});  
        });
    </script>           
</head>
```

Comment: Post the code inside `<head></head>` in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might want to try and clean up your code, move your css to a separate file and run your javascript at the bottom of your code after closing body tag. keeping these stuff separate will help when debugging errors in your code. just a tip for the future.

Comment: Changing how opencart manages to load various files are outside of my scope, and frankly it should not need to be done in order to fix a cross browser issue. While i totally agree it would be optimal, it would still not fix the issue, and therefore checking this as an accepted answer does not seem correct, sorry :)

Comment: Which version of opencart do you use?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Code.  Also, do some HTML validation.  With the CSS, JavaScript, and HTML all combined together, it makes it difficult to validate and troubleshoot (especially without knowing which version of HTML we should validate).  Often though, validated code helps to prevent browser variations, since some browsers are more forgiving than others.

Check out http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this one time with Server Side Include. It was because some files included by the Web Server was having text encoding UTF8-"With BOM". I used Notepad++ to change text encoding to UTF8-"Without BOM" and it solved immediatly the issue.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I tried cleaning the ~15 utf8 BOM files and although I was optimistic, this did not seem to clear the issue.